# Can't update table 'tbl' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1442

```
 INSERT INTO `category_sport` (
`id` ,
`category_id` ,
`sport_id` ,
`ordering`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', '1', ''
)
```

what I want to do is manually add few rows to the table for the testing purpose. But when I try to add it gives me below error

**#1442 - Can't update table 'tbl' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

table structure

[image: table structure]

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_category_sport_order` AFTER INSERT ON `category_sport`
FOR EACH
ROW UPDATE `category_sport` SET `ordering` = NEW.id WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

How can I add data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write PHP code manually to fix this.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,240978#msg-240978

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace NEW.id with scope_identity()

Comment: My fault. It's mysql and not sql server. Did you try: LAST_INSERT_ID()